# How to display more than one image in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make something that you can compare images and choose the one you like the best in pygame, how can I display multiple images in one screen?

Comment: It would be the same as drawing one image. Just create another member in a different position. I suggest reading some tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load a second image and reposition it next to the first image object.
Here is a tip on how to work with positioning: [Pygame Image position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165686/pygame-image-position)